# What is a valid range for Intake Manifold Pressure while driving on +60mph?

Tags: pressure, intake-manifold, vacuum-leak

So today I was monitoring my car data and logging everything, when I was driving on the highway going +60mph and on ~2500RPM, my intake manifold pressure read +10Psi. I read it's usually near 5Psi. On idle, mine is around 5Psi.

Is this normal?

Comment: Is that a gauge or absolute reading? Makes a big difference. What is the car? Turbo? Supercharged?

Comment: The intake manifold pressure is not speed dependent but rather load dependent.  For instance 60 mph going downhill is likely to produce a LOW manifold pressure (i.e. a vacuum) while 60 mph uphill will make for a relatively high pressure.  A 5 psi reading at idle, however, sounds about right.  Are you diagnosing a specific problem or just curious?

Comment: @jwh20 - It really depends on the vehicle ... most stock vehicles I've seen do not produce positive pressure (either turbo or supercharged) until under load, and *never* at idle. 5psi at idle seems very high and 10psi under load even higher, especially driving down the highway at 2500rpm. Most stock vehicles don't produce more than 7-8psi, and many under that.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It's going to be +5 psi relative to +14 (or so) psi ambient.  Which makes 5 psi a vacuum which is what it should be.  If the intake was actually at +5 psi (i.e. about 19 psi) that would be an impossible reading even with a turbo or supercharger since they will not create 5 psi of boost at idle.

Comment: @SolarMike it's what the ECU is reading. The car is 2006 Mercury Milan, base 2.3l not turbo/super-charged.

Comment: @jwh20 it's neither, it was a flat road mostly. I am diagnosing a lean system running, I got 27% Long-Term-Fuel-Trim reading and trying to figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Everyone if it is not pressure induction then it is correct.